# Spring Boot startup process

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a spring boot project that suddenly takes more time before the startup completes and I am at a loss about the cause. I would appreciate any insight into the cause and how I can resolve it. Below is a snippet from the log output:

```
2023-03-14 10:36:04,113 [restartedMain] DEBUG o.h.i.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl               - Adding Integrator [org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator].
2023-03-14 10:36:04,247 [restartedMain] DEBUG o.h.i.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl               - Adding Integrator [org.hibernate.secure.spi.JaccIntegrator].
2023-03-14 10:36:04,395 [restartedMain] DEBUG o.h.i.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl               - Adding Integrator [org.hibernate.cache.internal.CollectionCacheInvalidator].
2023-03-14 10:36:04,660 [restartedMain] INFO  org.hibernate.Version                              - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.9.Final}
2023-03-14 10:36:04,760 [restartedMain] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Environment                      - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2023-03-14 10:36:04,913 [restartedMain] DEBUG org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceBinding           - Overriding existing service binding [org.hibernate.secure.spi.JaccService]
2023-03-14 10:36:04,995 [restartedMain] DEBUG o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator              - Cannot default RegionFactory based on registered strategies as `[]` RegionFactory strategies were registered
2023-03-14 10:36:05,131 [restartedMain] DEBUG o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator              - Cache region factory : org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCachingRegionFactory
2023-03-14 10:36:05,288 [restartedMain] INFO  org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version           - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2023-03-14 10:36:05,449 [restartedMain] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry               - Adding type registration boolean -> org.hibernate.type.BooleanType@2801d36c

...

2023-03-14 10:42:34,943 [restartedMain] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column                       - Binding column: Ejb3Column{table=org.hibernate.mapping.Table(bulk_transfer_details), mappingColumn=resp, insertable=true, updatable=true, unique=false}
2023-03-14 10:42:35,569 [restartedMain] DEBUG o.h.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder                 - MetadataSourceProcessor property resp with lazy=false
2023-03-14 10:42:36,171 [restartedMain] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.AbstractPropertyHolder           - Attempting to locate auto-apply AttributeConverter for property [com.ideationhouse.paddieswitch.domains.BulkBankTransferDetail:resp]
2023-03-14 10:42:36,799 [restartedMain] DEBUG o.h.cfg.annotations.SimpleValueBinder              - building SimpleValue for resp
2023-03-14 10:42:37,413 [restartedMain] DEBUG o.h.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder                 - Building property resp
2023-03-14 10:42:38,008 [restartedMain] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column                       - Binding column: Ejb3Column{table=org.hibernate.mapping.Table(bulk_transfer_details), mappingColumn=response_code, insertable=true, updatable=true, unique=false}
2023-03-14 10:42:38,639 [restartedMain] DEBUG o.h.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder                 - MetadataSourceProcessor property responseCode with lazy=false
2023-03-14 10:42:39,298 [restartedMain] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.AbstractPropertyHolder           - Attempting to locate auto-apply AttributeConverter for property [com.ideationhouse.paddieswitch.domains.BulkBankTransferDetail:responseCode]
```

Many thanks.

Comment: `that suddenly takes more time before the startup completes`, how much now than before ?

Comment: Judging by the log, over 6 minutes is being spent starting up Hibernate. Have you made any changes to your application's entities or its Hibernate configuration? Alternatively, has the database that you're using changed at all? Perhaps these some more Hibernate logging in the 6 minutes period that shows where the time's being spent.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I commented out most of the recent changes and pointed the application to an in-memory database, however, this hasn't stopped the issue either. The application spools out outputs like the one listed in the question continuously even after 10 minutes without a successful start. ```2023-03-14 14:15:14,931 [restartedMain] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.AbstractPropertyHolder           - Attempting to locate auto-apply AttributeConverter for property [com.ideationhouse.```

Comment: @PeterMmm it seems that the application has entered an endless cycle without a successful start with outputs like: ```2023-03-14 14:18:07,332 [restartedMain] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.AbstractPropertyHolder           - Attempting to locate auto-apply AttributeConverter for property ```